# NodeJS/JavaScript: TypeError: Employee is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two files:

C:\p\nodejs\public\Test.js:

```
    var Employee = require('./Employee.js');
    var employee = new Employee();
```

C:\p\nodejs\public\Employee.js:

```
    function Employee() {
        this.name = "";
        this.dept = "general";
    }
```

With nodejs installed, I run:

```
    C:\p\nodejs\public>node Test.js
```

and get the error:

```
    C:\p\nodejs\public\Test.js:8
    var employee = new Employee();
           ^

    TypeError: Employee is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\p\nodejs\public\Test.js:8:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
        at startup (node.js:136:18)
        at node.js:963:3
```

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add export to `Employee.js`

```
function Employee() {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}

module.exports = Employee;
```